# What is the proper way to output data to Form from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a Form1 and I do some processing in the other class.
What would be the proper way to output information to Form1 `textBox9` ?

This is how I do it, but it only work partially, only when the form is active.

This is what I have in my class:

```
var form = Form.ActiveForm as Form1;
if (form != null)
{
 form.updateLabel("DBadd[" + counter + "]" + NAME2);
}
```

This is that I have in my Form1:

```
    delegate void updateStatus(String value);
    public void updateLabel(String value)
    {
        if (textBox9.InvokeRequired)
        {
            updateStatus del = new updateStatus(updateCodemicroLabel);
            textBox9.Invoke(del, new object[] { value });
        }
        else
        {
            {
                textBox9.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how my class called:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        new className().runTask();
    }
```

Comment: Fyi, `textBox9` is a horrible (default) name. You should really rename your controls to something meaningful!

Comment: How is the "class" in the first block instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Form.ActiveForm` you need to pass the instance to the class so it can call `whatever.updateLabel()` with `whatever` being the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to return the data is to implement a method in the worker class and get the return value in the Form's member variable or configuration parameter. Depending on the task executed by the class the task might need to execute in a background worker thread and then update the Form's member variable. For more information on how to run tasks in a background thread, please look at MSDN.

References & useful pages:

- ["BackgroundWorker Class (System.ComponentModel)"  [msdn.microsoft.com]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)